# Unable to access contents of only certain DVDs

Tags: dvd, multimedia, drm

I am using the NexStar DX Bluray drive enclosure with LG WH14NS40 internal Bluray drive with Pop!_OS. For some reason, there are some DVDs which simply do not seem to work. Usually, when I insert a Bluray or DVD disc into the drive, a popup will appear on my screen informing me what has been inserted, I can see the disc in the sidebar of my file manager, and I can access the contents with MakeMKV (although I have followed tutorials online, I have never been able to get VLC to play the DVDs directly). There are some DVDs for which none of this is true (I have not yet encountered any problems with any Bluray discs). Instead, the light on the enclosure continues to flash rapidly, and nothing else happens. I am lead to believe that this implies Pop! is trying to access the disc. The disc never appears in any UI and cannot be accessed with MakeMKV. `mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom` does not terminate until I turn off the enclosure. Another answer said that one does not usually `mount` media DVDs, and suggested running `cd-info --dvd`. With a problem disc inserted, that command only outputs its copyright/version message and then hangs until I turn off the enclosure (at which point it terminates with a `SIGINT`). When run with a non-problem disc inserted, it outputs the following and then terminates normally:

```
cd-info version 2.1.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003-2005, 2007-2008, 2011-2015, 2017 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
CD location   : /dev/cdrom
CD driver name: GNU/Linux
   access mode: IOCTL

Vendor                      : HL-DT-ST
Model                       : BD-RE  WH14NS40 
Revision                    : 1.02
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : Yes
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
__________________________________

Disc mode is listed as: DVD-ROM
CD-ROM Track List (1 - 1)
  #: MSF       LSN    Type   Green? Copy?
  1: 00:02:00  000000 data   false  no   
170: 95:59:74  431849 leadout (968 MB raw, 843 MB formatted)
__________________________________
CD Analysis Report
ISO 9660: 4036384 blocks, label `SCI_FI_CREATURE_CLASSICS        '
Application: DVD Studio Pro:4.2.2, DSPInterface:431.40, DVDAuthoring:428.45, DVDBase:468.61(Encoder: 614), Oxygene:427.3
Preparer   : 
Publisher  : 
System     : 
Volume     : SCI_FI_CREATURE_CLASSICS
Volume Set : SCI_FI_CREATURE_CLASSICS
UDF: version 1.02
```

A final curiosity of my problem is that I... do not believe it is caused by copy protection (though I'm really not sure, this is not an area of expertise of mine). One of the problem discs is part of a box-set that seems to otherwise give me no issues, ie the other 4 discs in the set can all be read just fine. I'd assume they should all have the same copy protection (all of the boxes say the contents are copy protected), but one of them just cannot be accessed. The only piece of technical information on the boxes that appears to be different is that the box for the problem disc lacks the "DUAL-LAYER FORMAT" text, which the other DVDs in the box set seem to have.

In the interest of eliminating common issues that I do not believe apply to this situation:

- Yes, I have libdvd installed (and libdvdcss)
- Yes, the same discs with the same drive, and enclosure, all work when connected to a Windows device

Comment: Have you installed libdvdcss?

Comment: yes, I seem to have libdvdcss installed